# how to remove click on primeng listbox element, only use the checkbox property

Tags: angular, primeng

> my requirement exactly
> Two listbox 1 and listbox 2

In list box1 contains every element have checkbox and one view icon button

in list box1 whatever the checked items that will reflect in listbox2 no issue here

but my issue is while clicking on the view icon button then checkbox also selected

I Want to restrict this checkbox selection here while clicking on view icon button

Please help here

```html
<p-listbox [style]="{'width':'95%','height':'280px'}" [listStyle]="{'max-height': '205px'}"
              showToggleAll="false" [options]="unMappedCodes" [(ngModel)]="selectedUnMapCodes" checkbox="true"
              multiple="true" filter="true" (onChange)="onChange($event)">
              <p-header>
                <div class="ui-grid-row">
                  <div class="ui-grid-col-10">
                    <div class="text-left"><b>{{mappedUnmappedCodeTitle}} : {{totalCount}}</b></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </p-header>
              <ng-template let-code pTemplate="item">
                {{code.label}}
                &nbsp;
                <button pButton type="button" icon="fa fa-eye" class="roundButton ui"
                  title="View" style="float:right;margin-top: -1%;"
                  (click)="showDialog(code)"></button>
            
              </ng-template>
            </p-listbox>
```

how to remove click on primeng listbox element, only use the checkbox property

Comment: please add your code, or a link to stackblitz with your code

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the css properties.

The `li` that has the pointer-event set needs to have to removed, and set it only to the checkbox.

If you add a stackblitz with your code, I can help you with something more accurate, but the idea is to use something like this:

```
:host ::ng-deep .p-listbox .p-listbox-list .p-listbox-item {
  pointer-events: none;
}

:host ::ng-deep .p-checkbox .p-checkbox-box {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

where the first is for each list item in the listbox, and the second for the checkboxes.

Again, this is generic, if you add a link to your code I can help you with something more specific

Comment: i am added my exact requirement in question